# Uploading .blend to sketchfab

Tags: model, upload, 3d, blender

Whenever I upload a model to Sketchfab I don't see any of my materials or texture. I tried uploading .blend, tried other export formats that blender supports, too. Same results. Am new to the 3d environment. Please pardon me for any ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

For textures, try enabling **File → External Data → Automatically Pack Into .blend**

I would also recommend the Blender to Sketchfab Exporter plugin ( https://sketchfab.com/exporters/blender ) which ships natively with Blender 2.70+

You can also manage materials and texture manually, after upload, using Sketchfab's Material Editor ( https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/202512446-Material-Editor )

However, it sounds like you might not have your UV maps set up correctly.

If you're still having trouble, contact support@sketchfab.com